# Oracle trigger is giving error - active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

Tags: oracle, triggers

I wrote a trigger which calls a procedure at the  end , procedure is having one commit statement .
When i execute trigger then its giving me error "cannot commit in Trigger".
Then i declared PRAGAMA AUTONOMUS_TRANSACTION but that is also giving error "active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back" , "error during execution of trigger"

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  Test_Ord_Update   
    AFTER  
    insert or update on test1  
    for each row  
    
    declare
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      l_exst number(1);
      v_id NUMBER (5);
    begin
    
     merge into test2 b
            USING dual a
            on (:new.id = b.id)
            when matched then update set
              b.price1 = :new.price1,
             b.price2 = :new.price2
           when not matched then insert (id, price1, price2)
             values (:new.id, :new.price1, :new.price2);
          select id into v_id from test2 where price1 =  :new.price1;
          LOAD_PRICE(v_id);
    end;
```

Comment: you never commit or rollback in a trigger. The session doing the work needs to do the commit or the rollback

Comment: @Cyrille MODIANO here i dont commit inside trigger but sub program which i need to call in trigger that have Commit statement . how to achieve this?

Comment: Autonomous transaction is executed in a new session, and it is not finished (committed or rolled back) at the end (when the execution returns to the current session). This is what Oracle says. Check [9i docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e4100.htm#1656) for more details

Comment: @astentx commit is mentioned in sub program which called in trigger.any way to achieve commit which executing in sub program of trigger?

Comment: You should check the concept of autonomous transaction. It has isolated context, so it doesn't know anything about main program. Either commit inside the autonomous transaction or do not use it at all

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e4100.htm#1656

Comment: @astentx - so that means Trigger cannot call a sub program  which has a Commit statement ?

Comment: @astentx - ohh now i understand what are you saying, i just wrote Commit next to the line where call sub program and its working fine because we need to commit or roll back after returning to main block.Thanks a lot

Comment: Using an autonomous transaction for something other than logging is almost certainly a bug.  Do you realize, for example, that the session that did the `insert` can rollback their transaction now and the changes made by your trigger and the stored procedure won't be rolled back?  So the data in the tables will be out of sync.  Or that if the `load_price` procedure queries `test1` that it will see the previous values not the changed values that caused the trigger to fire?

Comment: @JustinCave - So you mean to day that here i am using autonomous transaction that's wrong?i should only do the commit after insertion and then call the procedure that would be sufficient?

Comment: @vim - Yes, architecturally, this is a bug (or a couple of bugs).  My guess is that `test2` should really be a view or a materialized view rather than a table, there should be no trigger, and the process that loads data into `test1` should call `load_price` when it is done, and `load_price` should not have a `commit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we are calling a sub program in a trigger which has commit statement , we must need to write a commit after the line where we called sub program. like below

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  Test_Ord_Update
AFTER
insert or update on test1
for each row

```
declare
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  l_exst number(1);
  v_id NUMBER (5);
begin

 merge into test2 b
        USING dual a
        on (:new.id = b.id)
        when matched then update set
          b.price1 = :new.price1,
         b.price2 = :new.price2
       when not matched then insert (id, price1, price2)
         values (:new.id, :new.price1, :new.price2);
      select id into v_id from test2 where price1 =  :new.price1;
      LOAD_PRICE(v_id);
      COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: As noted in above comments, this will more than likely result in data corruption.